# How can I do a manually login method with my own model? Django

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to do a manual log in method with my own model I read the documentation but I don't understand how to use 
this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    # Redirect to a success page.
    ...
else:
    # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
    ...
```

this is my model Usuario:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):

id_usuario = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
correo_electronico = models.EmailField()
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=50)
usuario = models.CharField(max_length=255)
contrasenia = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True ,blank=True)
id_perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fecha_creacion =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
fecha_cancelacion = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is meant to be used for default authentication system.  But, given your user model, I think you are looking for custom authentication system.  It is best to see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/).  In short, you need a custom model, forms, and backends.  You should also make sure your settings.py specifies which backend Django is supposed to look for.